# Using 次 as a counter

Tags: numbers, counters

In cases such as [第二次全世界戦争]{だいにじぜんせかいせんそう} or [第二次]{だいにじ}スーパーロボット[大戦]{たいせん}, is [次]{じ} effectively just acting the way a number followed by st/nd/rd/th would in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is and and it is always preceded by both a 「[第]{だい}」 and a number.

In my own words, 「第N[次]{じ}」 is used to describe the ordinality of an unpredictable event of the same kind like a war or a boom.

We use 「第N[回]{かい}」 to describe the ordinality of a planned event of the same kind, such as an annual event.

Comment: `二次会` does not have `第`.  Is that due to its somewhat informality?  Also, for planned events, what about `周` compared to `回` like `第10周年記念日` or something?

Comment: @istrasci Thinking about your question there a bit more, my guess would be that 周年 functions in a similar manner to "annual" in English (e.g. "10th annual spelling bee")