# The difference between adding 第 and 次 to numbers

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Both 第 (prefix) and 次 (suffix) both seem to have the effect of turning it into an ordinal (eg: "two" into "second"). And sometimes they are both used, like 第二次大戦. When does one choose one over the other, or choose both? How do they compare/contrast?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14915/45489

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 次 as a counter](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/using-%e6%ac%a1-as-a-counter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

次 is a counter/unit with specific meanings. It's used in three types of situations:

- Counting or numbering *phases*, *waves* of one big phenomenon/event. 次 tends to be used for things that happen randomly but eventually finish, whereas 回 is used for regularly scheduled events and programs.

  > 3次販売 third sale (of a popular product)
  > 2次災害 secondary disaster
  > 攻撃は4次に分けて行われる Attacks will be done in four waves.
- (Math) Counting a *degree* of a polynomial.

  > 3次関数 cubic function
  > 2次方程式 quadratic equation
- Saying *primary*, *secondary*, *tertiary*, and so on to describe the order of importance (3次 and larger are uncommon)

  > 2次的な目的 secondary purpose
  > 廃熱の2次利用 secondary utilization of waste heat

As for 第1/2次世界大戦, I think 次 was used because the two World Wars were considered to be parts of a larger historical process.

On the other hand, 第 is just like "no." or "-th".

> 第3会議室 Conference Room 3
> 第4開発部 Development Division IV
> 交響曲第5 Symphony No. 5
> 第3王女 Third Princess

Its primary purpose is to make an ordinal/label and avoid confusion (3会議室 would mean "three conference rooms"). 第 is common in stiff fixed phrases such as 第2次世界大戦. But since there is usually no ambiguity when 次 is present, it's often safe to drop 第; for example, 3次販売 and 第3次販売 are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict, and 第二次 simply means *'the second time'.* 第二 means *the second* and 次 means *time.*

Yes it's possible to say 第二大戦 to mean *'the second war',* but most people would interpret it as *'the second (the inferior) war, the war that is the second in class',* implying there is a 'greater war'.

Such is the habit of the Japanese (or Chinese, since this is Kango) language, to say *'the second time* 第二次' instead of *'the second* 第二'.